# How to modify date style with hsqldb driver >= 2.6.1?

Tags: timestamp, hsqldb

Ho,
I created a database with hsqldb 2.4.1. But now I can't edit date or timestamp values in my database since i updated it with driver hsqldb 2.6.1 or 2.7.1. I can see in versions informations that there is a lot of work about timestamps and dates formats with this latests versions...

So actual date format with hsqldb 2.6.1 and 2.7.1 is now like this **52703-03-11**... It looks like dates years are long number, and I don't understand what is the year exactly behind 52703 number ?

So, if I try to edit with ISO date format **2019-03-11** I'm getting the error message below :

```
Can not bind statement parameter
  data exception: datetime field overflow
```

It's same thing with TIMESTAMP fields...

For information DDL to create my table is :

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.PUBLIC.INVENTAIRE (
    "DATE" DATE NOT NULL,
    "Besoin" VARCHAR(500),
    FKRENTREE BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10120 PRIMARY KEY ("DATE"),
    CONSTRAINT INVENTAIRE_FK FOREIGN KEY (FKRENTREE) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PUBLIC.RENTREE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX SYS_IDX_INVENTAIRE_FK_10125 ON PUBLIC.PUBLIC.INVENTAIRE (FKRENTREE);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10120_10122 ON PUBLIC.PUBLIC.INVENTAIRE ("DATE");
```

So, I would like to know how to modify date style format with hsqldb driver >= 2.6.1 in order to not depend later versions updates.

I tried to edit with quotes like '2023-03-11' but same problem.
I trie to execute `SET datestyle = 'ISO, DMY';` But I've got the error message `SQL Error [42501]: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATESTYLE`

Comment: I add that I tried to edit with DBeaver 22.0.3 with hsqldb driver 2.6.1 and Also with LibreOffice base : same problem, date format '2023-03-11' is not recognized ...